# Disk is full and cannot start MongoDB, How to drop databases or tables

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

```
root@mongo_node_1:~# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             42G     0   42G   0% /dev
tmpfs           8.3G  1.3M  8.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       2.9T  2.9T     0 100% /
tmpfs            42G     0   42G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            42G     0   42G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
tmpfs           8.3G     0  8.3G   0% /run/user/0
root@mongo_node_1:~# e
```

I have deleted the 20G mongod log file, but the disk is still insufficient, so I can only delete some  databases or tables to free the disk.
However, mongod cannot be started now. Can I delete the database or table without starting mongod?
By the way, there are three database nodes. Only the shard1 server disk  is full.

Answer (score 0):

If your shard has more then one replicaSet member you can delete the entire data folder content and the member will init sync its content from other members , if it is only one member and running under the default wiredTiger storage engine it is best to not delete files from the data folder since you could easily corrupt the content. It is best if you shutdwon the member , extend the partition offline and start the member again ...